# Pass two java List to GSON/JSON

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I want to pass two `List<String>` to Gson and catch them with `$.post` in my jQuery. Currently I have my first list in my servlet:

```
String json_list = gson.toJson(suggested_list);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json_list);
```

and I get it with the $.post like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".word_sugest").click(function() {
    var physical_exam =  jQuery("textarea#examination").val();
        $.post("MyServlet", { examination : physical_exam},function(responseJson) {
        var $textarea = $('<textarea rows="10" cols="20" id="words_suggested">').appendTo($('#words'));
        var areavalue = $('#words_suggested').val();    
            $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
            $('#words_suggested').val($('#words_suggested').val()+value+"\n");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How can I get another list with the same `$.post` Ajax-event? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be to have your AJAX call return a JSON object rather than a list. That way you can name your lists. Here's an example of how the output would look:

```
{
  list1: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  list2: ["R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W"]
}
```

This is done by creating a Java object like this:

```
public class CustomObjResponse {
  private List<String> list1;
  private List<String> list2;
  // Getters/setters
}
```

Then, when you have the object populated with both lists, your Gson call would look like this:

```
String json_obj = gson.toJson(customObjResp);
```

Comment: I'd add one more alternative to return an array of some class objects, where the class would contains only one list object, but definitely +1 from me. Also note that in fact OP's servlet *already returns a JSON*.

Comment: How am I going to call each list with individually with my jQuery?

Comment: By calling `responseJson.list1` and `responseJson.list2` respectively.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to create an extra class you can try out `List<List<String>>` solution.

Comment: But a List of Lists is a really ugly data type with poor semantics. You have to ask yourself, "What data am I representing?" I've never had data that was correctly modeled by a list of lists. (not saying it's wrong, just that I've never seen the need to be so hackish)

Comment: Artificial creation of classes may be even more ugly as well. You should understand that a list is simply a collection, when a class represents some 'entity'. So you say that two collections are less representative than a class whose instance contains a dummy list1 and list2 objects? And what if a new list should be added? Or an additional field? You'd introduce 3 dummy classes to confuse all people around? Can't agree with you, especially in the situation OP faces.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be to return a list of list objects and parse them with JavaScript accordingly:

```
List<List<String>> suggestedList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
suggestedList.add(new ArrayList<String>);
suggestedList.add(new ArrayList<String>);
String jsonList = gson.toJson(suggestedList);
```

Comment: In this situation how can I get each list individually in my jQuery?

Comment: These are two lists. Access them with two `$.each` loops (the second one nested), just the way you iterated over one list, but with an additional iteration inside.

Comment: In this situation I have a list of objects. How can I have two separated list e.g. List<cars>, List<bicycles> and get them both with a $.post?

Comment: You can have `List<List<Vehicle>>`, where `Vehicle` is the common superclass. If they don't share `Vehicle`, they will share `Object`.

Comment: Ok bad example :). I have a List<String> and a List<objects>. I run my servlet to get a List<String> which are some words and I use those words to query through a database so as to get a List<Objects>. In this situation I have to populate two Lists that are independent. Is it possible to populate them both with toJson?